# How can I launch Nuke from within Maya?

Tags: python, maya, mel, nuke

I seem to be doing something improper here and I am dumbfounded on what it is. I am trying to launch The Foundry NUKE from within Maya, and when I try I get this error relating to a module not found. But if I load up Nuke on a regular command line it loads up perfect fine. Seems something related to Maya's Python interpreter not able to find this module?  I can't seem to find it...

Update #1: I have even tried doing some sys.path.appends of the Nuke plugin, DLLs, lib, and include dirs before all of this to no avail...

Update #2: I've reinstalled my Python and verified that it is 64 bit.  Also checked my Maya and Nuke versions which are 64 bit.  I've tried the following as well... opening up a normal Python command prompt outside of Maya to load Nuke via an os.system call and it works.  It is only when doing an os.system call of Nuke in Maya that it fails with problems importing this _socket module.  When checking what _socket module Maya is loading I get:

```
import _socket
print _socket.__file__
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\Python\DLLs\_socket.pyd
```

Leading me to believe that Maya's Python is loading a diff version of this _socket then what Nuke is and something is going wrong there.

Original Code/Errors:

```
C:\Program Files\Nuke9.0v8\Nuke9.0.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/plugins/init.py", line 22, in <module>
      import nukescripts.ViewerProcess
    File "C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/plugins\nukescripts\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
      from nukeprofiler import *
    File "C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/plugins\nukescripts\nukeprofiler.py", line 2, in <module>
        import socket
    File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
        import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/plugins/init.py : error interpreting this plugin
```

---

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import maya.cmds as cmds
import os, sys
#import subprocess


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(314, 216)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Dialog.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Dialog.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.blastBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.blastBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 130, 75, 23))
        self.blastBtn.setObjectName("blastBtn")

        self.blastBtn.clicked.connect(self.RunPlayblast)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Playblast & Nuke Me", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.blastBtn.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Blast", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


    def RunPlayblast(self):
        cmds.playblast(fmt="qt", f="myMovie.mov", fo=True)
        self.RunNuke()

    def RunNuke(self):
        nukeExe = r'C:\Program Files\Nuke9.0v8\Nuke9.0.exe'
        myTemplate = r'B:\home\nukePBTemplate.nk'

        os.system('"'+nukeExe+'" -x ' +myTemplate)

        #command = nukeExe+" -x "+myTemplate
        #subprocess.Popen(command)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance() 
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    blastMe = Ui_Dialog()
    blastMe.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: The DLL error reminds me of one cause: you may have installed Nuke for a different bit version of Python. 64-bit Python modules are built for 64-bit Python, and 32-bit Python modules are meant for 32-bit Python. Consider eliminating a possible endian mismatch by uninstalling and reinstalling the correct version.

Comment: Thank you.. I am wondering now if this is the culprit.  I will have to look into that... as the missing module it complains about has been added to path, but it still complains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use built in subprocess to call nuke like this

```
import subprocess
nukeProcess = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/Nuke9.0.exe", "-x", "B:/home/nukePBTemplate.nk"])
```

And I think you never use a mel.eval("system /whatever") since you trying from python, already python has many built in methods to deal with system commands, like subprocess, commands etc ..

**Update**

```
import subprocess, os
newEnv = os.environ.copy()
newEnv["PYTHONPATH"] = newEnv["PATH"] + "/local/share/python/2.7/libs"
nukeProcess = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files/Nuke9.0v8/Nke9.0.exe", "-x", "B:/home/nukePBTemplate.nk"], env=newEnv)
```

Comment: This has been tried.  It does not get around the above error relating to the _socket module.  Thanks though.

Comment: Maya has its own pythonpath, probably that is actually messing up nuke pythonlibs. I don't have access to a windows machine but in my linux box it works fine. updated answer with example

Comment: This does NOT work.  I have changed /local/share/python/2.7/libs path to my C:/Python27/libs path and I still get the same errors above.

Comment: Will give this the benefit of being partially right.  The PythonPath was fighting me and constantly being changed, which seemed like the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `system` MEL command inside your Python script. To do that you need to use `mel.eval` method with string argument (string inside string). The purpose of the `eval` command is to provide a way for the user to execute a MEL command or procedure which can only be determined at runtime.

```
import maya.mel as mel

def RunNuke(self):  
    mel.eval('system "/Applications/Nuke10.5v5/Nuke10.5v5.app/Contents/MacOS/Nuke10.5v5 --nc --nukex"')
```

**I'm running Non-commercial version of NUKEX on a macOS (not Windows) and it works.**

Full version of your code should look like this:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import maya.cmds as cmds
import os, sys
import maya.mel as mel

class Ui_Dialog(object):

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(314, 216)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth( Dialog.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth() )
        Dialog.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.blastBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.blastBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 130, 75, 23))
        self.blastBtn.setObjectName("blastBtn")
        self.blastBtn.clicked.connect(self.RunPlayblast)
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Playblast & Nuke Me", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.blastBtn.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Blast", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

    def RunPlayblast(self):
        cmds.playblast(fmt="qt", f="myMovie.mov", fo=True)
        self.RunNuke()

    def RunNuke(self):
        mel.eval('system "/Applications/Nuke10.5v5/Nuke10.5v5.app/Contents/MacOS/Nuke10.5v5 --nc --nukex "')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance() 
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    blastMe = Ui_Dialog()
    blastMe.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

If you still experiencing problems with NUKE's launch from within Maya, try to run it in `safe mode`:

```
import maya.mel as mel

def RunNuke(self):  
    mel.eval('system "C:\Program Files\Nuke9.0v8\Nuke9.0.exe" --safe --nc --nukex')
```

> Read it: [Launching NUKE and HIERO in safe mode](https://support.foundry.com/hc/en-us/articles/206986449-Q100038-Launching-Nuke-NukeX-NukeStudio-Hiero-in-safe-mode).

If it still doesn't work I think it's a bug in your Python library or it's an issue in content of init.py.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work.  To simplify... I went into Maya's script editor and typed the following into MEL:

system "C:/PROGRA~1/Nuke9.0v8/Nuke9.0.exe --nukex"

I still get the same error:
C:/PROGRA~1/Nuke9.0v8/plugins/init.py : error interpreting this plugin
This leads me to believe this is something related to Maya's Python not finding the module above.  If I run Nuke on the command line like above, it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Move init.py to other place and try one more time... I reckon the problem is in it.

Comment: They are all added to sys.path so that is not the problem.  I am thinking now it is related to 32/64 bit mismatch as stated above since Maya's Python may be using a different bit version.

Comment: If you need lines in init.py try to write them in menu.py

Comment: I see problems in <module> import nukescripts.ViewerProcess and in <module> from nukeprofiler import *...

Comment: What's your Python version?

Comment: Try NUKE's safe mode.